# Working with a Java library from .NET

Tags: java, .net, interop

I need to work with a third-party Java library from .NET.

Can anyone recommend a more elegant way to do this short of using a local socket connection to a Java wrapper.

The information I've come across so far seems a little out-dated, and suggests things like using COM.

The library is used to connect to a server. I think some RMI stuff is happening internally. Does that rule out using IKVM? (My very brief tests with ikvmc resulted in lots of warnings, but I haven't looked into these yet.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI wont work - it is langauge specific.

You can run:

- Client / Server (program a server in java, then a web service called from .NET)
- COM... but you need to expose the java stuff in COM first, which is not easy. But you can access C++ from Java... and from there go to .NET ;)
- Code your own stuff.

Basically there is no common ground here. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the complexity of the library, [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) might be a viable way to actually run the code of the Java library on .NET.